# How to verify JWT id_token produced by MS Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure, jwt, adal

I have an angularjs SPA web app which uses [ADAL-JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) (and adal-angular).
It's set up to authenticate vs our corporate AD in MS Azure. The log-in flow seems to work correctly, and the SPA receives an id_token.

Next, when the user clicks a button, the SPA makes a request to a REST API I am hosting on AWS API Gateway. I am passing the id_token on the `Authorization: Bearer <id_token>` header.
The API Gateway receives the header as intended, and now has to determine if the given token is good or not to either allow or deny access.

I have a sample token, and it parses correctly on https://jwt.io/ but I have so far failed to find the Public Key or Certificate I should use to verify the signature. I have looked in:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/discovery/keys
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration (to get the jwks_uri)
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys

I *think* I should use the value of the x5c property of the key in https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys matching the kid and x5t properties from the JWT id_token (currently `a3QN0BZS7s4nN-BdrjbF0Y_LdMM`, which leads to an x5c value starting with "MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQY..." ). However, the https://jwt.io/ page reports "Invalid Signature" (I also tried wrapping the key value with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----").

Also, is there a (possibly python) library that can facilitate the verification of a given id_token as in the case above (so that I won't have to go grab the signing key on the fly myself?)... The best I could find ([ADAL for python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python)) doesn't seem to provide this feature?

Comment: have you seen [this](https://github.com/Azure/msrestazure-for-python/blob/master/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py#L166)

Comment: hey @4c74356b41 - thanks for the link! Could be handy but.. I don't see where the token signature is checked in that lib?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best solution I could put together so far:

**Grab the certificate** (the first value in the `x5c` property array) from either `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys`, matching `kid` and `x5t` from the id_token.

**Wrap the certificate** in `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n` and `\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (the newlines seem to matter), and use the result as Public Key (in conjunction with the id_token, on https://jwt.io/ ).

Of course, your actual use case will likely be to have some program validate the incoming JWT id_tokens, so your goal won't be to simply get the token to validate through the web UI on https://jwt.io/.

For instance, **in python**, I need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import jwt
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

PEMSTART = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
PEMEND = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"

mspubkey = "The value from the x5c property"
IDTOKEN = "the id_token to be validated"
tenant_id = "your tenant id"

cert_str = PEMSTART + mspubkey + PEMEND
cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str, default_backend())
public_key = cert_obj.public_key()

decoded = jwt.decode(IDTOKEN, public_key, algorithms=['RS256'], audience=tenant_id)
if decoded:
    print "Decoded!"
else:
    print "Could not decode token."
```

For a list of JWT libraries in various languages, see [the JWT Site](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io).
I'm using [pyjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/), and its [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) dependency (which has binary dependencies, so needs to be built and packaged for the target OS).

And then, of course, you can **verify additional details such as the claims** as [recommended here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#validating-tokens).

Comment: I have not coded python ever before. Based on what i understand you should not do this as signing keys that Azure AD uses can be rolled over very frequently and starting this year Microsoft doesn't even inform as the expectation is that programs/applications handle it seamlessly. See below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover

Comment: @Gopi Kolla you are absolutely correct. As a matter of fact, beyond this initial code (which was aimed at figuring out how the token verification would work), I am already grabbing the MS public keys (on a daily schedule, as they suggest checking every 24 hrs) and saving them where I can use them on-demand.
But I am interested... if one is not supposed to do all the work I've been staring at (and slowly chipping away at)... how can one use MS Azure AD to auth and NOT be a .NET App (running on Azure)?

Comment: The keys are in JSON  web key format like as of the post time of this comment: {"kid":"X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk","nbf":1493763266,"use":"sig","kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlF...."}

It follows the standard defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517,

Comment: I'm getting 2 keys when I query https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys. How do I know which key to use? After I decode the token I am able to see the x5t in the header, but thats after decode. Should I try with both and see which succeeds?

Comment: @sargeMonkey See "Token Validation" here: https://francescorizzi.github.io/AWSomesauce/articles/BAS4-pws/index.html
"Among the keys listed, find one with the kid (and x5t) properties matching the kid value from the token to be validated"
and code (TokenValidator) in https://github.com/FrancescoRizzi/AWSomesauce/blob/master/articles/BAS4-pws/custauth/custauth.py

Comment: I'm getting the error `TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object`. I believe, the problem is with the statement `cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str, default_backend())`

Comment: `pip install cryptography pyjwt requests`. There's also a snippet here to refresh the signing keys: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/147#issuecomment-722379003

Comment: Please note that python-jose is able to use JWS token dictionary obtained with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/discovery/v2.0/keys`.


See this snippet as an example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/blob/83a67bd97d6a97f2094b3044a40879dbc1ef6feb/Function/secureFlaskApp/__init__.py#L77-L105


Also, PyJWT has a class `PyJWK` that allows to easily convert a key dict to an actual key: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/jwt/api_jwk.py

Answer (score 2):

For a JVM solution, using `com.nimbusds:numbus-jose-jwt:4.29` is the most straight forward way to parse and validate a signed RSA256 id_token. The following Scala code parses the JWT token with a JSON Web Key:

```
    val jwt = SignedJWT.parse(token)

    val n = new Base64URL("Your Modulus Component of RSA Key")
    val e = new Base64URL("AQAB")
    val rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(n, e).keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE).algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.RS256).build()

    val verified = jwt.verify(new RSASSAVerifier(rsaKey))
```

Your application would still need to fetch the JSON Web Key Set from Azure Active Directory B2C `discovery/v2.0/key` dynamically to get the set of keys potentially used by AAD B2C. This should probably be cached and have a TTL of not more than 24 hours for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is there a (possibly python) library that can facilitate the verification of a given id_token as in the case above (so that I won't have to go grab the signing key on the fly myself?)... The best I could find (ADAL for python) doesn't seem to provide this feature?

For what it's worth, [MSAL Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python), which is ADAL Python's successor, validates the id token under the hood, and [provides you the decoded claims inside an id token](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/13#issuecomment-506544762) for your app. So that your app - which just obtained that id token via MSAL Python - can consume it locally.

> Next, when the user clicks a button, the SPA makes a request to a REST API I am hosting on AWS API Gateway. I am passing the id_token on the `Authorization: Bearer <id_token>` header. The API Gateway receives the header as intended, and now has to determine if the given token is good or not to either allow or deny access.

Usually id token is not used "on the `Authorization: Bearer <id_token>` header" to send to 3rd party for authorization purpose. YMMV.

Comment: Is this valid for the OP's question? It sounds like they are taking a token provided by the FE client library, sending it to the BE where it needs to be validated. I'm in a similar conundrum: using `@azure/msal-react` client-side and needing to send to Django/DRF server to validate the token is valid and that it belongs to the person who sent it. It isn't entirely clear if MSAL Python has this functionality or if it works for token that were retrieved through it.

Comment: @cjones I'm currently trying to validate a `jwt token` from `React` on the `Django API` and it's been blowing my mind for a week now. If you have solved your problem and there is a sample code somewhere, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this NodeJS code to validate the token

```
        const config = await fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration").then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
        const jwks = await fetch(config.jwks_uri).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
        const tokenHeader = JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[0]));
        const publicKey = jwks.keys.find((key) => key.kid === tokenHeader.kid);
        if(!publicKey) {
            throw new Error("Invalid token");
        }
        const publicKeyPEM = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${publicKey.x5c[0]}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;
        const data = verify(token, publicKeyPEM);
```