# How to validate a JWT from AzureAD in python?

Tags: python, jwt, azure-active-directory, signature, jose

I have set up an authorization server using AzureAD.
For testing it I am currently applying an implicit flow and to get a token and id_token I use https://oidcdebugger.com/.

Now I am trying to figure out how to properly validate a the token on the resource server side.
I always get a `jose.exceptions.JWTError: Signature verification failed`.
Can you help me find out what I am doing wrong?
I am really new to JWT validation and probably there is some obvious error somwhere.

As defined by the OIDC metadata endpoint at
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` keys
for signature validation can be found at
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys`.
The key ids on that endpoint match the `kid` value in my token headers.
So, I am positive that those are my keys.
They look like this:

```
{
   "kty": "RSA",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "<the-key-id>",
   "x5t": "<the-key-id>",
   "n": "<a-long-hash>",
   "e": "AQAB",
   "x5c": ["<a-long-hash-I-guess-thats-the-public-key"],
   "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/v2.0"
}
```

In the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142716/how-to-verify-jwt-id-token-produced-by-ms-azure-ad) the key is constructed by hand using `cryptography.x509`.
I tried the same but I had to change a few details to make it run.
I am `.encode`ing the string and I have to pass an iterable to the `decode` function.

```
import requests
from jose import jwt
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

AZURE_TENANT_ID = '<my-tenant-id>'
AZURE_KEYS = requests.get(url='<my-jwks_url>').json()['keys']

PEMSTART = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
PEMEND = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"


def decode(token: str, keys: list):
    token_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token=token)
    x5t = token_header['x5t']

    key = [d for d in keys if d['x5t'] == x5t][0]
    mspubkey = key['x5c'][0]

    cert_str = PEMSTART + mspubkey + PEMEND
    cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str.encode(), default_backend())
    public_key = cert_obj.public_key()

    return jwt.decode(
        token=token,
        subject='<my-subject>',
        audience='<my-audience>',
        issuer=f'https://sts.windows.net/{AZURE_TENANT_ID}/',
        algorithms=['RS256'],
        key=[public_key])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I am not supposed to validate the (access) token, only the id_token signature. The validation with `jose` also works by just supplying the key dict as `keys` argument (no need to construct certificate).

Apparently the (access) token from AzureAD is not necessarily a standard JWT. It's just supposed to be used for accessing the MS GraphAPI: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-529537264

Answer (score 0):

Also in my case I was using custom signing keys so I had to supply my `appid` in both the discovery and JWKS URLs.

Discovery: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid={app_id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid=%7Bapp_id%7D)

JWKS: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid={app_id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid=%7Bapp_id%7D)

More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validate-the-signature