# How to validate bearer token in Python

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, bearer-token

I have used below code to get the token:

```
def get_token():
        try:
            r = requests.post(
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + config_data['TENNANT'] + "/oauth2/token",
                data={"grant_type": "client_credentials",
                      "client_secret": config_data['CLIENT_SECRET'],
                      "client_id": config_data['CLIENT_ID'],
                      "resource": config_data['RESOURCE']})
            if r.status_code == 200:
                ret_body = r.json()
                return ret_body['access_token']
            else:
                log.error("Unable to get token from oauth {}, {}".format(r.status_code, r.json()))
                return "false"
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Exception occurred while getting oauth token {}".format(e))
```

In order to validate the token received from above code, I am trying to execute below line using JWT:

```
data = jwt.decode(token, key, algorithms=['RS256'])
```

Where can I get the key from? Or is there any other way of validating the token?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use online service for generating bearer token? I used https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt and it works fine.

Comment: @YuriR Can you provide a simple code to generate and valid token please.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using azure. If so, To decode a JWT token issued by `login.microsoftonline.com`, you will need to obtain the corresponding public key

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195081/how-to-validate-a-jwt-from-azuread-in-python] - This will give you reference for keys using discovery to get public key.

For that, you need to parse the request and find the `public key` in Azure AD metadata document.

```
import json
import requests
import jwt

response = requests.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + config_data['TENNANT'] + "/discovery/keys")

metadata = json.loads(response.content)

kid = metadata["keys"][0]["kid"]

public_key = metadata["keys"][0]["x5c"][0]

decoded_token = jwt.decode(YOUR_TOKEN, public_key, algorithms=["RS256"])

print(decoded_token)
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have other queries

Comment: Just tried this and I am getting error `ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=75497580, lib=9, reason=108, reason_text=no start line)>])`

Comment: @SAndrew - https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys - Can you try this  new version URL (Also, refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195081/how-to-validate-a-jwt-from-azuread-in-python)

Comment: Also, this if the error is for deserialise (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337833/could-not-deserialize-key-data-on-decoding-jwt-python)

Comment: Not sure why I am still getting the same error, I will keep on searching but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SAndrew - Can you update the post  with the solution that you tried  and error that occurred with the question. This helps to answer your question and solve the issue.